# SumIf with elements from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, sumifs

I have been working on my skills in VBA and althought I have made decent improvement over the last month and so, I'm still having a couple of problems regarding some the basics.
I have been on a loop to sum elements from a column who fall under a criteria with a sumif (which in this case was a table header/cell is equal to string), but I have been facing a problem that I believe related to the fact that the targeted cell and the source columns are both in different sheets :

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
c = wkb.Sheets("F").UsedRange.Columns.Count
targetLastRowIndex = wkb.Sheets("F").Range("A7:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
indexCol = wkb.Sheets("FF").UsedRange.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

TargetCell = wkb.Sheets("FF").Cells(7, 2)
For i = 1 To c
If wkb.Sheets("FF").Cells(6, i).Value = "FG AG" Then
wkb.Sheets("FF").Range("C7").Activate
ActiveCell.formula = "=SUMIF(wkb.Sheets("F").Range(Cells(7,29):Cells(targetLastRowIndex-1,29)),wkb.Sheets("FF").Range(Cells(7, 2)),wkb.Sheets("F").Range(Cells(7,i):Cells(targetLastRowIndex-1,i)))/1000"
```

Here the source sheet is named "F" and the destination sheet is named "FF"

Also, the next thing I want to do with this is to apply the formula to the cells underneath "C7" but I think I'm going to face a bit of a problem since I don't have knowledge of any method that would prevent the arguments from changing after applying the AutoFill

I hope that this question wasn't a stupid one although I don't think I was successful in putting this problem to words and I apologize for that.

Thank you again for helping me starting my little journey with VBA.

Comment: `ActiveCell.formula = "=SUMIF(wkb.Sheets("F").Range(Cells(7,29):Cells(targetLastRowIndex-1,29)),wkb.Sheets("FF").Range(Cells(7, 2)),wkb.Sheets("F").Range(Cells(7,i):Cells(targetLastRowIndex-1,i)))/1000"`... this is conflating VBA and formulas.

Comment: vba, items should be removed from the `""` and concatenated using `.Address` to create the correct string.

Comment: @ScottCraner The `.Address` method worked beautifully, thank you.
I wanted to point out that the code is only working if activate or select sheets everytime which I find annoying, I tried referencing elements using `ThisWorkbook.sheets` but it didn't work.